# What time is needed for overnight oats

Tags: food-safety

I want to know what is the minimum time required to soak oats to make them overnight oats. Now a days it’s Ramadan and I have very tight schedule on which I get 2-3 hours to eat. 
I wanted to know how much time is minimum required for overnight oats?

Answer (score 3):

I learned, long ago, that when a recipe calls for "overnight" it means eight to ten hours and sometimes twelve. The range depends on what you are soaking. Sometimes eight is enough and sometimes longer is needed because the ingredients are a variable that may not be consistent.

So the oats need to be tested. If eight hours is enough then eight hours it is. If not, you need longer.

Answer (score 2):

2 hours would be pretty tight,but doable. The problem is you'd get not very much nutrition--the soaking helps you digest. Better off preparing for the next day to whether you're thinking of

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a guess at around 8 hours, which I would say is an average duration of sleep for an adult - assuming the oats are prepared just before sleep and eaten just after.

As such, you could make the oats during the day for consumption when you are permitted.

Comment: when u say "when you are permitted". what do u mean?

Comment: permitted means allowed. As I understand, you're only allowed to eat during a certain period, as you've mentioned in your question, so what I mean is that you make it such that the oats have soaked for the 8 hours prior to when you're allowed to eat